# Ansible reports requires boto.rds (boto >= 2.26.0) even though boto 2.38.0 is installed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, ansible, rds

With Ansible version 1.9.1:

```
ansible --version
ansible 1.9.1
```

On Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I'm using the Ansible rds module to create a database:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  sudo: no

  tasks:

    - name: get-boto-version
      local_action: command python -c 'import boto; print boto.__version__'

    - name: Launch RDS instances
      rds:
        region: eu-west-1
        ec2_access_key: "{{ ec2_access_key }}"
        ec2_secret_key: "{{ ec2_secret_key }}"
        command: create
        instance_name: test
        instance_type: db.m1.small
        tags:
          this: that
        db_engine: MySQL
        size: 10
        username: foo
        password: foobar1000
        vpc_security_groups: this
        subnet: that
```

I want to add tags to the database, but when I run my playbook I get the following error:

```
    ansible-playbook -i ec2 simple-db.yml --extra-vars "ec2_access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} ec2_secret_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" -v

    PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

    TASK: [get-boto-version] ****************************************************** 
    changed: [127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["python", "-c", "import boto; print boto.__version__"], "delta": "0:00:00.138097", "end": "2015-05-21 08:36:55.233037", "rc": 0, "start": "2015-05-21 08:36:55.094940", "stderr": "", 
    "stdout": "2.38.0", "warnings": []}

    TASK: [Launch RDS instances] ************************************************** 
    failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true}
    msg: Parameter tags requires boto.rds (boto >= 2.26.0)

    FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

    PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
               to retry, use: --limit @/home/chris/simple-db.retry

    127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

This is despite having a later version of `boto` installed. See output of task `get-boto-version` above and ...

```
$ python -c 'import boto; print boto.__version__'
2.38.0
```

I'm running in a `virtualenv`.  Have tried setting the PYTHONPATH to explicitly point to the location of `boto` in the `virtualenv`, but no dice.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you ran the same command in ansible and see what it's going to print out?

Answer (score 0):

As an inventory variable (either in `$project_root/group_vars/all` or `$project_root/host_vars/localhost`), specify:

```
#$project_root/group_vars/all or #host_vars/localhost
ansible_python_interpreter='/usr/bin/env python'
```

Or directly in the inventory file like:

```
# inventory file
localhost ansible_python_interpreter='/usr/bin/env python'
```

That should get you squared away.

Ansible by default won't pickup the env python.

Comment: Thanks for that DefionsCode.  

I actually want it to use the Python in the virtualenv which it _appears_ to be doing anyway as adding a `local_action: command which python` yields the path to the virtualenv python: `"stdout": "/home/chris/src/.hc-inf/bin/python"`